# go append to an interface key/field which is a map

Tags: go

My question is about appending to a map which is a filed/key of an interface. This is required to build a JSON object. I am using `map[string]interface{}` to be able to append any struct types to it. I am not sure if that is a right way as I am still learning Go but I could not find a better way. Below is a link to a playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/cxpSep8OQD.

I think I need to use type accretion but I do not understand how. Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have are `Group` values, then declare `outJson` as a map of `*Group`:

```
outJson := make(map[string]*Group, len(groups))
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/Pa70O4Xs-e)

If the map can contain different value types, then use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to access the group:

```
    g, ok := outJson["a"].(*Group)
    if !ok {
        panic("handle error a better way")
    }
    g.Hosts = append(g.Hosts, "hostname")
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/LcHwLchyUm)

Comment: Unfortunately I have other types as well. Only one other type actually.

Comment: I did ! Thank you for your help !